# Ubuntu 18.04 will not boot after update

Tags: boot, 18.04, xubuntu, laptop, asus

I replaced the HDD in my ASUS F555L laptop with a Samsung EVO860 SSD. I then created a bootable USB using Rufus with the Ubuntu 18.04 iso.image from Canonical website. I plugged in the USB and started up the laptop. As far as I know, Ubuntu was installed onto the SSD because the system worked fine for a week, until there was a system update. After that I shutdown the laptop. Upon restarting, it would not boot up. The errors I get are:

1. PXE-E61: Media test failure, check cable
2. PXE-M0F: Exiting PXE ROM.

Reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media in selected boot device and press a key_

Any assistance would be appreciated.

EDIT: 
I reset the BIOS to Default, then tried to Boot with every option available, to no avail. So I created a new Bootable USB and after a few days of trial and error, finally got the install to work. On top of that, I have updated the system, shutdown completely, and restarted without issue. In short, it works!

I shutdown the PC, and started it back up while holding down Esc key to open the Boot Loader. From there, selected the USB, then Enter. I went through the install options, using Erase and Install, then ran it. After that, restarted and held Esc key again and selected the SSD drive, from which it booted and ran, and has continued to do so every time.

Thank you for offering some assistance.

Comment: Do you have network boot before UEFI boot  in UEFI settings. I never use network boot so turn that off totally so it does not try to find network while booting.

Comment: No, UEFI is the first boot option. In fact, i dont have an boot option labeled as 'network' at all.

Comment: Network is called PXE? And network boot then is not working since it cannot find it. If not first, then first entry in UEFI does not work, and UEFI is going to second or third, etc.